# Откуда передаётся объект MouseEvent в методы реализованные в MouseAdapter

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Начал изучать перехват событий с помощью MouseListener и в процессе возник один вопрос. Используя абстрактный класс MouseAdapter чтобы не реализовывать все методы MouseListner самому, хочу понять откуда переопределённым методам этого класса передаётся объект MouseEvent?

Answer (score 0):

Он передается из кода, которому вы передаете адаптер.

Например, Вы говорите панели: "На тебе мой адаптер на клик мыши, только кроме вызова, еще и передавай объект MouseEvent".
Панель такая: "OK".
Происходит событие, панель знает что нужно вызвать Ваш метод с аргументом MouseEvent и вызывает.